# Is There a Sencha Equivalent to jQuery's Radioset?

Tags: jquery-ui, mobile, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

jQueryUI has a pretty nice display for radio buttons:

[image: jQuery UI radioset]

Does Sencha have anything similar?

---

*Follow up question, if not:*

what do you find to be nice UX for a three-item (or even four-item) component which requires only one touch?  (e.g., a select box is two touches, one to open the select list and one to choose your option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`Ext.SegmentedButton`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.SegmentedButton) in Sencha Touch.

Sample code snippet:-

```
var segmentedButton = new Ext.SegmentedButton({

    allowMultiple: false,  // ensures only 1 button gets pressed at a time.
    items: [
        {
            text: 'Choice 1'
        },
        {
            text   : 'Choice 2',
            pressed: true
        },
        {
            text: 'Choice 3'
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        toggle: function(container, button, pressed){
            console.log("User toggled the '" + button.text + "' button: " + (pressed ? 'on' : 'off'));
        }
    }
});
Ext.Viewport.add({ xtype: 'container', padding: 10, items: [segmentedButton] });
```

Output :-

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks RR.

for others with the same question, this also working within a FormPanel, by making the xtype='segmentedbutton'

Comment: Hey @roadRunner, when using a segmenetedbutton in a form, is it typical to create a hiddenfield alongside of it and update the hiddenfield's value on change? (sencha 1.1)

Comment: No, I don't think so. Why do you want to create a `hiddenfield` ?.. If you want to get the value of pressed button, you can get it here .. `Ext.getCmp('segId').getPressedButtons()[0].getText()`

Comment: well, my sencha forms are generic/dynamic created by reflecting on my desktop site's view models. With that in mind, I don't necessarily know what element ids to look for in, say, a beforesubmit method.